# Custom names for tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-extensions

I want to have custom names for some tabs in latest firefox.

I have lots of tabs open and some of them represent different build of the same application. It means that I can see the same favicon and the same text. It would great if I can name them (ideally permanently as I have them bookmarked) like **v3.0**, **v3.0.4**, **v3.05**

```
So the tab name would be

3.0 for http://wwwdev/imacs/radek/3.0/pages/main/login.php
3.0.4 for http://wwwdev/imacs/radek/3.0.4/pages/main/login.php
3.0.5 for http://wwwdev/imacs/radek/3.0.5/pages/main/login.php
```

looks like [TabRenamizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2987/)  doesn't work with the latest firefox build.

Answer (score 3):

There's more than one way to skin this particular cat. For your usage, a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) script looks appropriate. Since the version of your application is easily extracted from the URL, the script might look like this:

```
var match_data = document.URL.match(/^[a-z]+:\/\/[^\/]*\/imacs\/radek\/([0-9.]+)\//);
if (match_data != null) {
    document.title = match_data[1] + " " + document.title;
}
```

Comment: will Greasemonkey make firefox slower?

Comment: I updated my question with some example what I want to achieve. So you think that I can use the script to make the document title rename in case I have new version 3.0.6?

Comment: @Radek: The script extracts the version number from the URL. You can easily adapt the regexp or the title construction expression if they're not exactly what you want. Greasemonkey will make every page load take about 1µs slower — in other words I don't think it makes any visible difference.